# MONGODB - Add duplicate field with different value

Tags: mongodb, duplicates

Is there a way to write a script that updates a document by adding a duplicate field with a different value? I cannot use set as that replaces the existing value. I cannot use push as the field is in an object, not an array. I even tried creating the new field with a different name and renaming it which also replaces the existing field.

Comment: You might want to show some code, or at least an example of the document and the field you're trying to replicate. Please also review [Ask].

Comment: {
    "_id" : "Mapping",
    "mapping" : {
        "A" : {
            "id" : "A1",
            "Mapping" : {
                "Required" : {
                    "code" : "code",
                    "id1" : "id",
                    "id2" : "id",
                    "id2" : "data.id",
                    "reference" : "reference",
                    "quantity" : "data.quantity",
                    "price" : "data.price",
                    "type" : "data.type"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Above is a shortened example of the document I am trying to update. I want to create another reference field with a different value much like there is two id2 fields with two different values.

Comment: Thanks. I would suggest putting the document snippet into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have duplicate fields in a Mongo record. A Mongo collection is a collection of documents, otherwise known as objects. You cannot have a duplicate field in an object and Mongo is no different.

Comment: I have existing duplicate fields in the same document I am referring to (see above). I did not add those ones myself so they may have been added by editing the document manually as opposed to using a script. However, I need to create a script in order to promote these changes to db in other env

Comment: I am not sure promoting these changes would be the way I'd go. I'd like to know what caused this to happen in the first place and remedy that. If you want to promote duplicate fields to a db, how do you know which one you will need to reference in the future? Maybe I am not understanding the situation, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB (and any other database that I have come across so far) is built around the idea that individual fields are identifiable so they can be filtered by, grouped by, sorted by, etc... That also explains why MongoDB does not provide support for the scenario you're facing. That being said, MongoDB can be used as a dumb datastore for arbitrary JSON data. And the JSON specification does not say anything about duplicate field names which is probably why you can actually store such a document in MongoDB in the first place.

Anyway, there is no way to achieve what you want without loading the entire document, changing it (by adding the duplicate field(s)) and then replacing the whole document. That, however, will work.

I personally cannot think of a reasonable scenario where this sort of document could make sense, though. So I would strongly suggest you revisit your document structure.